# Two Step Algorithm: Mapping an Input String to an Output String

Tags: python, algorithm

I've been puzzling over how to get a certain function working in Python. The function, takes positive integers to other positive integers as follows:

```
Phi_m(n2) = Phi_m(m*n + r) = m*x[n] + r*(x[n + 1] - x[n])
```

The above terms are all integer valued and are defined as follows:

```
n2 = the (n2)th slot of the output string

m = a fixed positive integer

n = some multiple of m such that n*m is less than or equal to n2

r = a remainder term to fill in the amount missing from n*m in decomposing n2

x[n] = the element in the [n1]th slot of the input string

x[n + 1] = the element in the [n1 + 1]th slot of the input string
```

In general we start with a string of numbers, say 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3 and end up with a string of (k+1)m-1 terms, where k is the number of terms you started with, excluding 0. To use the function we first fix an m, say m = 2.  Now we decompose n2 in terms of m, where n2 is representing a 'slot' of our output sequence. Say n2=5.  Then we are asking 'what is in the fifth 'slot' of our output string'.  In this case our total output string will be of length (5+1)2+1.  Notice that we do not count 0 - it is always present and is for our purposes the 0th term, hence we have 5 initial terms. To answer our question of what goes in the slot we take 5=2*2+1 as our decomposition.  Now that we have a decomposition we can apply our function:

```
F(x(5)) = F(x(2*2+1)) 2x[2] + 1(x[3] - x[2]).
```

The thing is, for Python to do this it has to know how to decompose each number. So it knows 2 is fixed, and knows 2*3 is too much and so chooses 2*2. Then it has to know this is too little and add remainder 1. Only once it's done this can it actually grab n = 5. That is, it can run the function. It seems clear that once it knows how to do this it can just run through every n in our range, but I'm really not sure how to program the meat of this function.

Now to answer some questions:  Is x a function? A list? A number? x[n] is essentially a list.

What do you mean when you say "values of an input string"? What's the signature of Phi_m?

The function acting on this list takes in a single element of the list, gives us a decomposition of the number somehow, and then applies the 'formula' you see above.  In this sense it is more of a two step algorithm.

Please let me know if this is unclear.  I will certainly continue revising until it makes sense to those reading.

Comment: Explain every variable for each function on a separate line. No sentences, please. First the data, then then explanation of your function.

Comment: This is very unclear.  You are asking for an algorithm.  To get one we need to know exactly what the inputs are and a clear definition of the outputs in terms of the inputs.

Comment: @zoranPavlovic I added a list at the beginning explaining each variable briefly.  Does this help?  Is there more that should be added?  Thanks!

Comment: What are the inputs and expected output(s), exactly.

Comment: @martineau Our inputs are integers and the outputs are integers.  We take in one at a time and output one at a time (after all the calculations are done).  For example, take the string is 0,1,1,2 and fix m=2.  We use the formula (n+1)m-1 to know how many outputs we want, in this case 4m-1.  We won't be able to get the last one with this string.  We take each 'slot' of the output as our input, and we output the value that fills that slot as the output (we 'fill in' the slots).  We do this for all 4m-1 values.

Comment: @Gene Has the above list clarified outputs and inputs at all?

Comment: You defined the input: "In general we start with a string of numbers, say 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3 and end up with a string of (k+1)m-1 terms, where k is the number of terms you started with." OK, I assume you mean a list object composed of those integer values. So what exactly would the "string of terms" you end up be, again assuming you mean literally another list object containing integer elements?

Comment: Sorry this is still confusing. Your last example breaks the explanation you gave earlier. You can't build an algorithm on shifting definitions of the output. The only thing I can offer is that decomposing `X = m*n+r`, `m>0` fixed, and `n,r>=0` is pretty simple: Just solve for `n` with int arithmetic: `n=floor(X/m)`. Then `r=X-m*n`

Comment: @martineau To clarify, by (k+1)m-1 terms I mean that the length of the output is (k+1)m-1 integer values.  The string of terms you end up with are the integer values computed by the function.  So say we use 0,1,2,2.  We compute an output string with, say, m=2, [F(0)=0, F(1)=1, F(2)=2, F(3)=F(2*1+1)= 2x[1]+([x[2]-x[1]) = 3, F(4)=F(2*2)=4, F(5)=4]

Comment: @gene It is probably better to disregard that paragraph, I have deleted it to make things more cohesive.  The algorithm can be made instead calculating (n+1)m-2 output terms (that is, we omit the last term because we don't have an x[n+1] term to use).  I think I was being too ambitious.  As for the decomposition that's very helpful.  My main concern though is how to implement it in Python, as unfortunately my programming skills are quite weak.

Comment: @martineau

Please do let me know if there's anything else that's unclear.  It will definitely help me in asking future questions.

Comment: This line `F(x(5)) = F(x(2*2+1)) 2x[2] + 1(x[3] - x[2])` makes absolutely no sense. (For one thing it seems to be missing an = sign, but even with this it's ill-defined. It might make sense if you said instead `F(x,5) = F(x,2*2+1) = 2x[2] + 1(x[3] - x[2])`.  Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this bit of code will get you close to the answer:

```
>>> def phi_m(x, m):
...   rtn = []
...   for n2 in range(0, len(x) * m - 2:
...     n = n2 / m
...     r = n2 - n * m
...     rtn.append(m * x[n] + r * (x[n + 1] - x[n]))
...     print 'n2 =', n2, ': n =', n, ' r =' , r, ' rtn =', rtn
...   rtn    
...
>>> x = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
>>> phi_m(x, 2)
n2 = 0 : n = 0  r = 0  rtn = [0]
n2 = 1 : n = 0  r = 1  rtn = [0, 1]
n2 = 2 : n = 1  r = 0  rtn = [0, 1, 2]
n2 = 3 : n = 1  r = 1  rtn = [0, 1, 2, 2]
n2 = 4 : n = 2  r = 0  rtn = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
n2 = 5 : n = 2  r = 1  rtn = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
n2 = 6 : n = 3  r = 0  rtn = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4]
n2 = 7 : n = 3  r = 1  rtn = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
n2 = 8 : n = 4  r = 0  rtn = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
n2 = 9 : n = 4  r = 1  rtn = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6]
>>>
```

Your original formula for length produced an out-of-bounds error as did the one in your comment.  The `m * len(x) - 2` is apparently what you meant.

Comment: The `len(x) * m - 1` is still one off.  You must have meant `-2`.  I've made that change. If this article is some help to you, hope you'll "accept" it.

Comment: Python is very picky about indentation. If you copied/pasted from the page you might have deleted or added spaces.  Or perhaps a tab character was created somewhere along the line.  Don't use tabs.  Try re-typing the spaces at the start of the line to make it look exactly like what's in the response.